# How do you add SSL for a secondary domain with Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, google-apps

Google Enterprise support said it was possible to add SSL to a secondary domain for Google App Engine but I don't see how to do it? They directed me to premium App engine support but I don't have that.

What i'm looking to do is add a SSL cert for a secondary domain that I have on my Apps Account. From what I have been able to find you can only add ssl for the primary domain.

If it is not truly possible to add a cert for a secondary domain for use with app engine I need to know how to split off the domain to its own apps account. From what I have seen in the past this takes a long time to do.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, it's possible to [use SSL on custom domains (primary or secondary)](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2644386), but not use Google Apps accounts to authenticate users via GAE Users API as described [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/182081).

So, if you have a `secondary.com` domain, you will be able to have a custom-domain SSL to `https://www.secondary.com`, but you will not be able to use Google Apps user accounts, e.g. `user@secondary.com`, to authenticate users against GAE Users API.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned at [1], Google Apps does not support secondary domains for App Engine apps, however it’s supported for domain aliases. If your requirement is primary or secondary domain, the only solution will be to open a new Apps account for that secondary domain and migrate all the user data, which can be a bit challenging.

If you decide to do it, you can follow these steps:

1. Rename secondary domain users to the primary domain (e.g. usera@secd -> usera@prid)
2. Delete secondary domain, create and setup a new Apps account for secondary domain. Deleted secondary / alias domain become available for registration immediately. There is no 24 hours wait period as with primary domains.
3. Migrate email data via [2] or GAMME. For Drive and Calendar migration use corresponding APIs or Marketplace apps. Group archives can’t be migrated. Settings will not be migrated too and have to be set manually or via API (where possible).

To minimize downtime and impact I recommend doing migration over weekend. If you have an annual commitment for the x number of users on your current Apps account, contact Apps support for assistance in reducing commitment after you perform migration to a new account and setup billing.

[1] - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl

[2] - https://support.google.com/a/answer/6003169?hl=en